# Prioritizing components spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, components

How can I prioritize components to load first?

Comment: Please add some code to make it clear what `a list with the components` means. Otherwise read about [`@Order`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html)

Comment: I change question.

Answer (score 2):

I find @Order annotations it will work

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html